# My transaction hasn't confirmed and it's been 9 days

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

Transaction was initiated May 16, fee was 0.0001 and it's 226 bytes. It's 9 days later and it hasn't confirmed.

- What is going on?
- How do I get my BTC back?

EDIT:

Sorry, since I posted as guest it seems to not let me respond/edit as original poster. Here's the blockchain info: https://blockchain.info/tx-index/836b863d4099493d5599ab20024b10d6087f0ea662ffd2d1feea54acbd4a1195

It says May 20th, but I did send it May 16th

Answer (score 0):

Your fee is extremely low. Blockchain is currently completely jammed up. Could you post transaction details so that any miners here can help?